# Jump loop based on the existence of a resource

Tags: javascript, xml, loops, http-status-code-404

I'm breaking my head trying to figure this out. I have an XML file of employees, and the photos are stored in a different server. I build the URL using the SQL query that creates the XML.

I need to display all employees that have a missing photo.

The function that reads the XML sequentially is as follows:

```js
function updateBoard() {
  var html;
  xmlDoc = "";

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET", "xml/no_photo.xml", false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Row");
  html = '<br><table class="transp" align="center"><tbody><tr><td valign="top"><div class="tbl_head_bright">Foto</div></td></td><td valign="top"><div class="tbl_head_bright"># Empleado</div></td><td><div class="tbl_head_bright">Nombre</div></td><td valign="top"><div class="tbl_head_bright">Departamento</div></td></tr>';

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onerror = function() {
      html += '<tr><td><span class="dchange_bright"> MISSING </span></td>';
      html += '<td><span class="dchange_bright">' + empid + '</span></td>';
      html += '<td class="left"><span class="dchange_bright">' + Nombre + '</span></td>';
      html += '<td class="left"><span class="dchange_bright">' + department + '</span></td></tr>';
    }

    img.src = x[i].getElementsByTagName("url")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    var Nombre = x[i].getElementsByTagName("nombres")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + ' ' + x[i].getElementsByTagName("apellidos")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    var empid = x[i].getElementsByTagName("emp_id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    var department = x[i].getElementsByTagName("departamento")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
  };

  html += '</tbody></table></div>'

  $('#mainboard').html(html);
}
```

This doesn't work. It won't display anything. The console displays a bunch of 404 errors which are the missing photos, but it shows nothing.

I tried using continue on the onload event, but it throws the error that continue is only allowed on a loop. Which I am, but obviously being inside a function breaks the logic.

I'm not super versed in javascript, I'm still learning and have a long way to go, so I'm missing some basic concepts as how loops and functions work and how the whole logic works, so please bear with me.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery for the ajax part as well?

Comment: Because the files are located in another server, and I can't access it through ajax. I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using my ETL. Couldn't find a way to do it via js.